# Install 32-bit Tomcat in a 64-bit Windows environment

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I need to run 32-bit tomcat8 with 32-bit JRE in a 64-bit Windows environment. Another 64-bit JRE was installed in this machine for some reason.

I installed tomcat8 with the 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service exe Installer. The installer always chooses to install 64-bit Tomcat8 on this machine, and it seems no way I can force the installer to install 32-bit tomcat even by specifying the 32-bit JRE during the installation process.

I was wondering if there is a way to force the installer to install 32-bit tomcat.

I found some explanation on the Tomcat setup page, does it mean I should uninstall the 64-bit java and then do the installation again?

> Java location: The installer will provide a default JRE to use to run
> the service. The installer uses the registry to determine the base
> path of a Java 7 or later JRE, including the JRE installed as part of
> the full JDK. When running on a 64-bit operating system, the installer
> will first look for a 64-bit JRE and only look for a 32-bit JRE if a
> 64-bit JRE is not found. If a JRE cannot be found when running on a
> 64-bit operating system, the installer will look for a 64-bit JDK.
> Finally, if a JRE or JDK has not been found, the installer will try to
> use the JAVA_HOME environment variable. It is not mandatory to use the
> default JRE detected by the installer. Any installed Java 7 or later
> JRE (32-bit or 64-bit) may be used.
>
> https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

The only architecture-dependent executables present in the Windows Tomcat distribution are those from the [Procrun project](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html):

- `prunmgr.exe` (which is always a 32-bit application) has been renamed to `tomcat8w.exe`,
- `prunsrv.exe` has been renamed to `tomcat8.exe`.

The latter can be a 32-bit or 64-bit executable and its architecture must match that of the JVM. Therefore you need to:

1. Download the Procrun distribution (cf. [download site](https://downloads.apache.org/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/)),
2. Extract the 32-bit `prunsrv.exe` (in the main folder of the archive) to `tomcat8.exe`,
3. Use `tomcat8w.exe` to reconfigure Tomcat to use the 32-bit JVM you have.