# How to migrate a 32 bit java web app to 64 bit?

Tags: java, tomcat, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I have a java web application which runs on tomcat 8.5 (as a windows service). This is a 32 bit application.  When I insatll the app it gets installed on C:/Program Files (x86)/ directory. I need to migrate this to 64 bit(for memory allocation issues) but I can't find any code/configuration file that might help me to do this.

I did some googling and found [This PDF](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but doesn't seem relevant. Where should I look for these code/configuration? Is there any standard way of doing this? 
I am sorry if this is a dump question. I haven't done this before so don't have any clue. I also don't have much information to provide but here are some that might help

1. My operating system is 64 bit
2. I have 64 bit java installed (checked with java -version command)
3. The tomcat8.exe (the windows service mentioned earlier) is 64 bit (Saw in Task Manager)
4. The installer and the web app was built by previous developers

**Update: Installed java is 64 bit. the 32 bit java.exe was coming from previous version of the application installed**

Comment: What do you want? Get Java as a 64 bit version installed? Or changing Tomcat to be 64 bit? Or do you want to modify your web application running on Tomcat to ba 64 bit?

Comment: There is nothing else to do: if you're running the tomcat with a 64-bit JVM, all is good

Comment: But then, why the installer is installing the app in (x86) directory?

Comment: “When I install the app it gets installed on C:/Program Files (x86)/ directory.”  What app are you speaking of?  What installer are you speaking of?  Is this an app you wrote?  Did you use an installer you built?

Comment: @VGR I have updated the description. Should have mentioned earlier.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like an issue with the installer.  Do you happen to know how that installer was built?

Answer (score 3):

Having the tomcat installed on (x86) directory it means you are using the 32 bit installation.
Your options are :

- Download the 64 bit installation for your Tomcat Version from https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/ and set the configuration from scratch.
- Manually change the tomcat's executable, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570171/install-32-bit-tomcat-in-a-64-bit-windows-environment) but in the opposite way.